# Why bitwise AND gives zero in javascript for operation 0b0010&0b0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011

Tags: javascript, binary

I don't understand why the result `0b0010&0b0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011` is 0 in javascript, The expected result is `0b0010` which is `2` in decimal.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the second number have more than 32 bits?

Comment: @JonasW. It's a 64bit number 0x3333333333333333

Comment: Javascript Numbers can only do bitwise math with 32bits

Comment: @JonasW.  Javascript represents all numbers as 64-bit double precision IEEE 754 floating point numbers (see the ECMAscript spec, section 8.5.) All positive integers up to 2^53 can be encoded precisely.  It explains my question. Thank you.

Comment: That doesnt matter. They can only do bitwise math with 32 bits.

Comment: nop. 0x2&0x3333333333333 still gives me correct answer which exceeds 32bit.

Comment: Because 0x2 doesnt exceed 32 bits?!

Comment: Try with `(2 << 31) & (2 << 31)`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, javascript can only handle 32bit bitwise operation. 0x2222222222222&0x33333333 gives the incorrect answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The TL;DR practical advice to take away here is that bitwise in JavaScript is limited to 32-bit signed ints, and so you shouldn't attempt operating on integers longer than 31 bits. But if that is not satisfying, read on to understand what actually causes this specific behaviour...

There are a couple of things worth understanding before trying to grok the exact mechanism of this behaviour:

### 1. Binary is not *binary*

The binary notation `0b` is a **Numeric Integer Literal** just like `0x`, it is not a *raw* binary data literal. The implication being: it is only interpreted as a *number*, whereas the *type* of variable being defined will determine the actual underlying bit format (i.e float vs int). The significance of this is that different types exhibit different behaviour at their limits, such as when defining numbers too large or with too much precision to fit.

### 2. Bitwise is for *ints*

JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floats AKA "doubles", yet bitwise operations are only valid on ints. This is because int bit formats are essentially the same as binary numeric literals; whereas floats are very different, they separate numbers into exponents and significands. To work around this JavaScript casts numbers into 32-bit signed ints (which can be fully represented within 64-bit floats) before performing bitwise operations.

### JavaScript bitwise beyond 53-bits

When sticking to the limits of 32-bit signed ints (31-bit integers with a sign) bitwise operations will work exactly as expected, and when going above 31-bits you can expect the bits above 31 to be lost just like in any other language. That is until you push past the 53rd bit... then you can expect some less obvious behaviour because past this limit the floating point format starts interfering with it (and not by merely masking the upper bits):

Unlike ints, floats always preserve the most significant bits when being assigned a number that is too long to fully represent rather than masking them off. It does this because it is more *numerically* valid, and it *can* do this because it stores the order of magnitude of the number separately in the exponent which allows it to shift the number so that it's most significant bits fit into the 52-bit significand window and round off the lower bits.

... Don't run away yet! I have diagrams!

So here in this unnecessarily detailed diagram is the full journey of your numeric binary literal input, it's conversion into a 64-bit float (and loss of 9 bits of precision), and conversion into a 32-bit signed int. Note that this is purely conceptual and not representative of the actual mechanisms.

```
    MSB (implicit 1)                                              
    │                                                             
 +0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011 <─ num
 │   └────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┘└───┐    
 │                            │                            round  
 │                            │                            carry  
 │   1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 <──┘    
sign └──────────────────────┐          │                          
  │     1084 = (2^10 - 1) + 61         │                          
  │     │                              │                          
  │     │ [ 11-bit exponent ]          │  [ 52-bit significand ]  
  │┌────┴────┐┌────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┐
  0100001111001001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 <─ f64
  │└────┬────┘└────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────┘
  │     │                              │                          
  │     │                              │                          
  │     1084 - (2^10 - 1) = 61 ────────────── 61 - 52 = 9 ───┐    
sign                                   │                   shift  
 │   1001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010 <──┘    
 │                            │                                   
 │                            │                                   
 │   ┌────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────┐         
 +0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011010000000000 <─ num
 │  │                              └──────────────┬──────────────┘
 │  MSB (implicit 1)                              │               
 │                                                │               
 │                                                │               
 └───────────── sign ─────────────┐            truncate           
                                  │               │               
                                  │               │               
                                  │               │               
                                  │┌──────────────┴──────────────┐
                                  00110011001100110011010000000000 <─ s32
```

Notice that the most significant digit in your input is in the 62nd place, which is 9 above the maximum signifiand representable in 64-bit float (53), and that has caused exactly 9 of the lowest position digits in the output to be zeroed, (the 9th rounded and carried).

Comment: I updated this comment because the original digressed too much into how it's not possible to set all of the underlying bit combinations in float-64 with integer literals due to their lack of negative exponents... but this really was not very relevant considering that it's the _numerical_ representation that is cast to the 32-bit int. Additionally I've added explanation and diagram of exactly why and how the low bits are zeroed. This should read as a more cohesive explanation if a little verbose - It was a good exercise for me to flesh out all the details at least.

Comment: plus one for ascii art

Answer (score 1):

The number in question cannot be represented exactly:

```js
console.log(Number("0b0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011").toString(2));
```

As you can see the rightmost `01100110011` has become `10000000000`. This number `&0b0010` equals 0. For the purpose of bitwose operations that number is also taken modulo 2<sup>32</sup> during ToInt32 abstract operation, but that's responsible for the loss of the most significant bits:

```js
console.log(("0b0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011" | 0).toString(2));
```

This number `&0b0010` of course also equals 0.

Specification: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

because the second number is too long for the type to contain. It works up to the following length in your example:

0b0010 & 0b0011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011

which is 3 iterations of your 0011 shorter than what you were testing with

Comment: Yes, 0x2&0x3333333333333 is 2 indeed, which 3 is repeated 13 times. 0x2&0x3333333333333333 is zero, 3 repeated 16 times. why?